# iframe browser back button issue for my history.js code

Tags: history.js

Below is my code working perfectly in my page but when i am calling same page in iframe it is not working

```
    function History.back() { alert('browser Back Clicked!'); History.forward(); };

(function(window, undefined) {
var State = History.getState();
History.replaceState({ state: 4 }, State.title, "?state=4");

})(window);
```

Comment: `function History.back() ` is invalid syntax.

Comment: but it is working in IE

Comment: this code is working in IE8 but if add same code in iframe page then its not working